# Prevent double post on form CakePHP 3

Tags: cakephp, post, double

I want to prevent double post on double click on the submit button.

I have this code to save the data:

```
public function reply($id = null){

        date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Amsterdam');
        date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

        $username = $this->Auth->user('username');
        $authorRang = $this->Auth->user('rang');

        $posts = TableRegistry::get('posts');
        $threads = TableRegistry::get('threads'); 

        $query = $threads->find('all');

        $last_post_date = date('m/d/Y h:i:s a', time());

        $replies = $posts->newEntity();

        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            //$token = $this->request->getParam('_csrfToken');

            $reply =  $posts->patchEntity($replies, $this->request->data);

            $reply['thread_id'] = $id;
            $reply['author'] = $username;
            $reply['created'] = $last_post_date;
            $reply['authorRang'] = $authorRang;

            $query->update()
            ->set(['last_post_date' => $last_post_date])
            ->where(['id' => $id])
            ->execute();

            if ($posts->save($reply)) {

                $this->Flash->success(__('Your reply has been saved.'));

                //return $this->redirect(['action' => 'view/'.$id.'']);

            }else{      
            $this->Flash->error(__('Unable to add your reply.'));
        }
    }
        $this->set('reply', $replies);
}
```

How can I prevent it?

I have tried many things but it doesn't work. I tried to unset the entity but it does not work. It still saves the data multiple times.

Thanks